# Ambien shadows affected by scaling in 3ds Max

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We're having some problems displaying ambient shadows with original scaling in 3ds Max.

This is a screenshot of a model with correct/original scaling (measure tool measures a 14m wall):
[image]

This is a screenshot of a model that we have scaled down to around 5% of its original scaling (measure tool measures a 0.7m wall):
[image]

We have the same viewer setting on both uploads, but as you can see, the ambient shadows only starts displaying when we scale our models down. This relates to all the 3ds Max models we have been testing on.

Is there any settings inside 3ds Max that could help us maintain the ambient shadows on models with normal scaling?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak the effect by getting a reference to the viewer's renderer and calling its `setAOOptions(radius, intensity)` method. For `radius`, try values between 0.0 and 200.0, and for `intensity`, values between 0.0 and 3.0. Example:

```
NOP_VIEWER.impl.renderer().setAOOptions(100.0, 1.0);
```

Keep in mind though that anything under `impl` is considered internal implementation and may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This worked out perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Cheers!