# Inexplicable reflection in models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Kindly take a look at this video for reference:

https://streamable.com/pg0sf

This was originally a Solidworks file which has been imported in 3ds Max and then translated to the Viewer as a .MAX file. As you can see, strange reflection occurs only on elements created in/still remaining from the original Solidworks file (video: see lower middle of the screen). The other objects have been re-modelled in 3ds as this seems to be the only way to avoid this effect. I have tried to delete unneccesary polygons, delete all materials and UVM's, but this reflection always occurs until the specific piece is deleted and modelled from 3ds Max itself. Any take on what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

I remember you were asking for a way to tweak the ambient occlusion effect in another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628390/ambien-shadows-affected-by-scaling-in-3ds-max) :) And this looks a lot like an ambient occlusion artifact. You'll probably need to tweak the `radius` and `intensity` properties to avoid this.